# IIS - комбинация анонимной и Windows-аутентификаций

Tags: безопасность, iis, аутентификация

Добрый день.

Есть сайт на IIS 8.0 (Windows 2008 r2), к которому должен быть доступ как у анонимных пользователей, так и у доменных пользователей. 
Если включаем на сайте проверку подлинности Windows, то доменные пользователи заходят нормально, но анонимные пользователи не могут попасть на сайт. Если дополнительно включаем анонимную проверку подлинности, то зайти на сайт могут все, но доменные пользователи тоже считаются анонимными.

Простейшим решением выглядит завести два сайта (с проверкой подлинности windows / анонимной), но в этом случае получается две гиперссылки на один логический ресурс, что по некоторым причинам неприемлемо. Точка входа должна быть одна.

Достаточно будет разрешить этот вопрос для одной страницы сайта (Login.aspx, лежит в корне сайта). На эту страницу всегда попадают те, кто заходит на сайт. На ней, в зависимости от типа аутентификации, отображается разное содержимое. Весь вопрос в том, как допустить до нее и анонимных пользователей, и доменных пользователей, и чтобы было понятно, пользователь какого типа зашел.
Для остальных страниц сайта приемлем анонимный доступ всех типов пользователей.

Что тут можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант:
Заведите отдельную страницу для доменной аутентификации, и закройте на нее доступ анонимным пользователям. На странице `Login.aspx` разместите ссылку вроде "зайти через домен", ведущую на эту самую отдельную страницу.

Вариант сложнее:
Напишите свой модуль, который бы начинал процедуру доменной аутентификации независимо от того, разрешен ли доступ на текущую страницу анонимным пользователям - но в случае неудачи запоминал этот факт в куках и оставлял бы пользователя в покое.

Но тут возможны лишние всплывающие окна в браузере, в которых пользователю придется нажимать "отмена", чтобы остаться анонимным - так что лучше все-таки пойти по простому пути.